# If a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal to each vector in a basis for a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}n$, then $v$ ...... .

Tags: linear-algebra

If a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal to each vector in a basis for a subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $v$ is orthogonal to every vector in $W$ .

I don't know how to prove this statement. All possible help appreciated!

Comment: Consider that any vector in $W$ can can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_r\}$ is basis of $W$ the Each vector $w\in W$ can be written as linear combination of elements of $B$, i.e.

$$w=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_rx_r$$, $a_1,a_2,...,a_r\in F$

Taking inner product with $v$ we have,

$<w,v>=<a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_rx_r,v>$

$=a_1<x_1,v>+a_2<x_2,v>+...+a_r<x_r,v>$

$=a_1.0+a_2.0+...+a_r.0=0$, which means that each vector of $W$ is orthogonal to $v$

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful example!

Comment: You are most welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{w_1, \dots, w_d\}$ be a basis for $W$ ($d < n$). We know for each $w_j$, $\langle v,w_j \rangle = 0$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is our inner product. Take any vector $w \in W$. We know for some $\alpha_j \in \mathbb{R}$, $w = \sum_{j=1}^d \alpha_jw_j$. Now, $$\langle v,w \rangle = \langle v, \sum_{j=1}^d \alpha_jw_j \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^d \alpha_j \langle v,w_j \rangle$$ Do you think you can conclude from here?

Comment: Yes, I can. Each evaluation of ⟨v,wj⟩yields 0, which is the sum of aj*0 from j=1 -> d. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! it is true.

Suppose $\{x_1,x_2....x_m\}$ is basis of Subspace $W$ then

Choose any arbitrary element $y$ in $W$ then We can write $y$ as linear combination of basis element. So

$$y={\alpha}_1 x_1+{\alpha}_2 x_2+......{\alpha}_m x_m$$ Now $$<{\alpha}_1 x_1+{\alpha}_2 x_2+......{\alpha}_m x_m,v>={\alpha}_1<x_1,v>+{\alpha}_2<x_2,v>+......{\alpha}_m<x_m,v>=0$$ Since $v$ is orthogonal to each basis element.

So it shows that $v$ is orthogonal to each element of subspace $W$.

Comment: Thanks as well for your answer!